# Joint distribution of maximum and minimum of a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution

Suppose $X = (X_1,X_2)^T \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu =(\mu_1,\mu_2)^T$ and 
$
\Sigma=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2
\end{pmatrix}
$.
The pdf of $\min(X_1,X_2)$ and $\max(X_1,X_2)$ is well known. But what is the joint distribution (or pdf) of $\min(X_1,X_2)$ and $\max(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: You may also want to see this (joint distribution of order statistics): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, 
\begin{align}
f(x_1,x_2)&=f(x_1,x_2)\Bbb I_{x_1<x_2}+f(x_1,x_2)\Bbb I_{x_1>x_2}\\
&=\Bbb P(X_1<X_2)\frac{f(x_1,x_2)\Bbb I_{x_1<x_2}}{\Bbb P(X_1<X_2)}+\Bbb P(X_1>X_2)\frac{f(x_1,x_2)\Bbb I_{x_1>x_2}}{\Bbb P(X_1>X_2)}\\
&=\Bbb P(X_1<X_2)\frac{f(x_{(1)},x_{(2)})}{\Bbb P(X_1<X_2)}+\Bbb P(X_1>X_2)\frac{f(x_{(2)},x_{(1)})}{\Bbb P(X_1>X_2)}\\\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! But I did not get why you multiply and divide $P(X_1 < X_2)$ at the second step. :(

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be the min and max.
$$
Pr(Y_1 \le s, Y_2 \le  t) = Pr (X_1 \le t, X_2 \le t)- Pr(s \le X_1 \le t, s \le X_2 \le t) = Pr(X_1 \le s, X_2 \le t) +Pr(X_1 \le t, X_2 \le s) - Pr (X_1 \le s, X_2 \le s)
$$
Taking derivatives,
$$
f(s,t) = \phi(s,t)+\phi(t,s),
$$
where $\phi$ is the pdf of the bivariate normal distribution.

Am I correct ?

Comment: This cannot possibly be correct, because if $t$ represents the max and $s$ the min, then the density must be zero wherever $t \lt s.$  This is why @Xi'an explicitly includes indicator functions $\mathbb{I}$ in his formula.